# Entity Relationship Diagram, can someone check for my erd whether its correct or not?

Tags: erd

Can someone check my ERD, because I don't know whether I'm doing it correctly or not. I'm not sure about the difference between strong and weak entity, what I'm sure is that strong entity has their own primary key.

Other than that, is it correct i need to take Payment_ID as foreign key in my order table ? and what other attribute that i could have in my ORDER TABLE

Maybe some suggestion on what to add or improve on my ERD. Here i have a image for my ERD. Thank You

[Entity Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVay2.png)

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not a good fit in SO. However if you indicate why you believe it to be wrong or why you are unsure...

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

`PAYMENT` has an `ORDER_ID` and `ORDER` has a `PAYMENT_ID`. Having both fields is redundant, I would remove `ORDER.PAYMENT_ID` which would be a nullable field if customers don't pay immediately.

`ORDER_DETAILS` requires a PK, either a surrogate key `ORDER_DETAIL_ID` or the combination of `ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID`.

Can a `PAYMENT` use only one or more than one `COUPON`? The cardinality on the crow's foot line says more than one, but the `PAYMENT.COUPON_ID` field would allow only one. A nullable `PAYMENT_ID` in the `COUPON` table would be a better choice.

You have some doubtful minimum cardinalities. A `CUSTOMER` must place at least one `ORDER`? Ok, I can accept that. An `EMPLOYEE` must take at least one `ORDER`? So everyone in the company must take orders, and you're not going to record employees until they've taken an order? Also, every `ITEM` must be referenced in `ORDER_DETAILS`? Are you not going to want to record items on offer before they're ordered?

Finally, a note on terminology: your diagram is better called a table diagram, not an ERD. To be called an entity-relationship diagram, a diagram has to distinguish the concepts of the entity-relationship model. The style of diagram you used doesn't distinguish entity sets (i.e. ID fields) from value sets (non-ID fields) or entity relations (tables with single-field PK) from relationship relations (tables with composite PK, i.e. `ORDER_DETAILS` is a relationship relation).